# how to show djago validation error message in html template?

Tags: django

I set max_length limit for my every form filed. I want when any user exceed max length limit then contact-form will not be submitted and showing an error message. such as if any user forget to fill name filed then it will show name is required or if it exceed max length limit then it will show "maximum 300 character allowed". here is my code:

```
#forms.py
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name =  forms.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=300)
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=3000)


#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
      current_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,default=timezone.now)
      name =models.CharField(max_length=300)
      subject =models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
      email =models.EmailField(max_length=300)
      message = models.TextField(max_length=3000)



views.py
@csrf_exempt 
def home_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
      contacts = ContactForm(request.POST)
      if contacts.is_valid():  
          name = request.POST['name']
          email = request.POST['email']
          subject = request.POST['subject']
          message = request.POST['message']
          post = Contact(name=name,email=email,subject=subject,message=message)
          post.save()
          
          context= {'message_name':name}
          return render(request, 'index.html',context)
        
        else:
           print('not submittd')

        
    fm = ContactForm()
    context= {'form':fm}
    return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

here is html code of my contact from:

```
           <section class="contact section" id="contact">
                <h2 class="section-title">Contact</h2>
 {% if message_name %}
                <div class="centerTest">
                     <h1> Thanks {{ message_name }} for your message. We will get back to you very soon</h1>  
                </div>
{% else %} 
                <div class="contact__container bd-grid">
                    <form action="#contact" method = "POST" class="contact__form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="contact__input">
                        <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="contact__input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="subject" name="subject" class="contact__input">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="message"  id="" cols="0" rows="10"   class="contact__input"></textarea>
                         <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LciYlMaAAAAAE28SyHrqdm9g6a43UGIf6_ImvF8"></div>
                         <br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="contact__button button">
{% endif %}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
```

I also try this in my forms.py but not seeing any error message:

```
#Validation #DataFlair
def clean_name(self):
  name = self.cleaned_data['name']
  if len(name) > 300:
      raise forms.ValidationError("maximum character exceed")
  return name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view at else when form is not valid:-

```
else:
  name = request.POST.get('name', None)
  if name:
     if len(name) > 300:
         name_error = "maximum 300 characters allowed"
  else:
     name_error = "Name required"
  context = {"fm":ContactForm(), "name_error": name_error}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

In html

```
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="contact__input">
   {% if name_error %}
   <small> {{name_error}} </small>
   {% endif %}
```

Alternatively you can ModelForm  or html validation(required and maxlength attribute for text input)

Comment: Sense-pro not working. nothing is showing

Comment: can you use a print below else and confirm if it is printing when form is not valid?

Comment: getting this error when submitting from "local variable 'name_error' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Can you update the code on question. I think there is some indentation issue.